# Could not load jQuery mobile templates in Windows Phone using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone, templating

I have a mobile application developed with PhoneGap. I'm using jQuery mobile templating. The application goes well with iOS and Android. In WP7.5, if I navigate to the web page via Internet Explorer, the application runs OK, without problems.

But when I build the xap in PhoneBuilder and deploy it to my WP7.5, all the templates that I'm using don't work. In the screen I could see: "The template footer could not be loaded. HTTP Status code: 0".

Should I have to do something special in order to be able to see the templates?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the answer I gave here [jQuery Mobile - error loading pages using PhoneGap and WP7.5 - issue with security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237595/jquery-mobile-error-loading-pages-using-phonegap-and-wp7-5-issue-with-securi/12620460#12620460) as it is probably what you are experiencing.

The solution is to mark your extra files as "content" in the properties dialog, rebuild and redeploy then everything should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before the templates issue, I have the issue with the images and I've solved it with changing the build action of the images to content. But now, all the templates have this configuration but they don't work... Any other idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: WHen you start the app in debug, you should get a load of "INFO:" lines being logged which tell you all the files that are being created in IsolatedStorage.  Are your template files in the list?

Comment: OK, it's a different problem then.  Could be the way JQM tries to load them?  I haven't used JQueryMobile templating.

Comment: Sorry Dave, I'll close the question. We are not using jQuery Mobile templating, we are using Knockout templating. I'll open a new question. Thank you very much for your help.