# "Error Loading Page" on changePage using Ajax

Tags: ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

So I have this nice PhoneGap application (cordova 2.7.0, along with jquery mobile 1.2.0) that works great on my Android phone. The www folder also works flawlessly using Firefox, Chrome (through wamp), IE 10, and it's ugly-but-useable on IE7.

Now, I've been stuck on some sad behavior when trying to get this app to work on my Windows Phone. (7.5) Here's the thing:

My index.html prompts the user for his credentials to log in to an external web server. This html file contains all the references to the javascript and css files used by my application. The different pages are then loaded through a content div using ajax, which is pre-filled with the log in form.

**My index.html body:**

```
<body>
<!-- Begin Page Connect -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
              <h1>Connect to Server</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" >
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-iconpos="none" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" id="col1">
            <h3></h3>
            <form id="formConnect" >
                    <label for="server_url" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Url Server:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="server_url" id="server_url" class="required defaultInvalid url" value="" placeholder="http://" data-theme="a" />

                    <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a" />

                    <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" class="required" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a" />

                    <button id="cb" disabled type="submit" data-theme="b">Connect</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Page Connect -->
</body>
```

Now when I click on connect, the client-server authentication process takes place:

```
$.ajax({
    url:server_url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {page: "login", username: user, password: passhash},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("LOGIN: SUCCESS");
        $.mobile.changePage("home.html", {transition: "slide"});
    }
});
```

The authentication ends succesfully (the console log outputs "LOGIN: SUCCESS"), and then this piece of javascript takes place:

```
$.mobile.changePage("home.html", {transition: "slide"});
```

And that's where I get the undebuggable "Error Loading Page" error, and the home page does not load.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8237595/1439597) and its answer but all of my files in www (including images) are already set as "Content" in their build action.

Also, after reading [this article](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/phonegap-wp7-breaks-jqm-ajax-page-loading) I thought of trying using an anchor right on my index.html page (just after the form):

```
<a href="home.html">link</a>
```

When clicked, the same "Error Loading Page" poped up. But when I added the data-ajax="false":

```
<a href="home.html" data-ajax="false">link</a>
```

Then the home.html file **would load** indeed, but would not work at all obviously, since it didn't contain any js or css reference, etc.

Also, I tried all of that **both on emulator AND actual Windows Phone (HTC HD7)**

Would anyone have any info on how to at least DEBUG this mean error message? "Error Loading Page" does not speak to me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, changePage using separate html files does not work on Windows Phone 7. (at least with my project) You have to put all your pages in one file.

So I just regrouped all of my page contents in one html file, putting each page's content in its dedicated div with the **data-role="page"** attribute and a specific page id, and now **changePage("#idOfThePage")** works perfectly on both emulator and actual device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as answering your question on how to debug it:

Have you tried using Weinre? It's a great debugging environment for stuff like this. It will give you access to a console and all the web development tools provided by current desktop browsers.

Link: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly, after thorough investigation, this tool does not work with Windows Phone 7.